# Limit category list view in WordPress Post edit

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to hide category list in WP admin when you are editing your post. As I have hundreds of categories the website is frozen until the category list is fully loaded. I would like to limit the number of categories to be displayed or simply not displayed and manually name the category to add the post to.

(I have a custom category named authors, but is the same)

[image: descriptive image]

Comment: Is this a programming question or a general wordpress question?  If the latter it fits better on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.  For instance [How can I hide a category from Contributors in the edit/add new post screen?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/8197) seems relevant.

Answer (score 1):

We actually dealt with a similar issue. Having hundreds of taxonomy terms causing the editor to take ages to load. This is an issue with hierarchical taxonomies (like categories) and not single level ones (like tags).

The first thing you may want to consider is remove the metabox with the [`remove_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/) function. You can remove the metabox by its handle which should be `taxonomy-slugdiv`:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'so60570776_remove_metaboxes', 100 );
function so60570776_remove_metaboxes(){
    remove_meta_box( 'my-custom-taxonomy-slugdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'anothertaxonomydiv', 'post', 'side' );
}
```

This will now allow you load the editor without having the enormous load time of the taxonomy's hierarchical checkbox list.

Now, the hard part is *how you want to implement letting people add/remove taxonomy terms (or categories) is **up to you***. You can build a searchable checkbox list, you can automatically add terms based on the current user, whatever works best for your particular scenario.

In **my** particular case, I built a custom metabox that lets users search for a taxonomy term, and will apply all the ancestor taxonomy terms along the way, making use of a couple AJAX functions. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Image of my neighborhood custom taxonomy selector]

I've got this set so that the text input runs a JavaScript function named `termQueryAdvanced` that runs a PHP function named `term_query_advanced` and returns the result via AJAX. Then once the neighborhood (like "Greater Newport Area") is clicked on, it adds it to the purple tag box under "Current Neighborhoods".

It basically makes use of the [`WP_Term_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) Class with the text input providing the `name__like` parameter to search for. When the desired one is clicked, it then uses [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) and [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) to apply that term and all parent terms (in my case, hierarchically, `neighborhood` > `city` > `state` > `country`) automatically.

I've also got some CSS on the purple tags to show an "X" on hover, which when clicked will use [`wp_remove_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/) which will take that term away.

This is all handled from a metabox I added using the [`add_meta_box()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) function on the [`add_meta_boxes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_meta_boxes/) hook.

My implementation is probably *much* more complicated than most people would need (and would require a lot of manipulation to even show on here), but I custom tailored it to my exact use-case. Again, it's up to *you* how you want to allow people to add taxonomy terms once you remove the metabox, and frankly there might even be plugins that can handle that for you, but I'm not personally familiar with any.

Comment: Thanks for the help Xhynk. Could it be easier? for example, not displaying all the terms existing by default but only display the term that you search for.

Comment: Yes. That would be for you to implement though through the `add_meta_box()` function. The first step is to remove the existing one with `remove_meta_box()`. Then how you want to display/select them is entirely up to you. I can't exactly just write the code for you though.